# Weird behavior with setTimeout inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, settimeout

First example (works as expected):

```js
let timer = function (i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i);
  }, i * 1000) // logging every second
};

for (let i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    timer(i)
}
```

This code works good, in console i can see logging for every second.

Now let's change delay of timeout to 1 hour (1000 * 60 * 60)

```js
 let timer = function (i) {
   setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(i);
   }, i * 1000 * 60 * 60) // logging every hour
};
    
for (let i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
   timer(i)
}
```

This code doesn't work as i'm expect it. I expected logging for every hour. You can try to run it by yourself.

Comment: `This code doesn't work as i'm expect it` => Please update your question and specify what does happen and what you are expecting to happen. We should not have to run your code to get the first and guess at the second.

Comment: " I expected logging for every hour" — And what does happen?

Comment: "You can try to run it by yourself." — And then wait for five thousand hours for it to finish?

Comment: @Quentin use "Run code snippet". Logging 5k times for ~ 5 seconds